# Forms won't submit in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, forms, firefox, form-submit

I have a variety of forms working on my site that work fine in all browsers except Firefox and I can't figure out why. The validation errors work fine, but once it's time to submit, Firefox won't do anything.

I know Firefox has had issues with submitting forms, but from what I can find it's usually when there is no submit button present, but I have one on my forms:
`<input value="Send" type="submit">`

Also, I've seen issues where the form was not attached to the dom, causing Firefox to fail as well, but my form is present in the dom (not jquery generated) so again, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the .js that submits for the form once all error are resolved:

`// Submit the form as long as there are no errors
        if (invalidFields.length == 0 || typeof invalidFields === 'undefined') {
          $("form.sd_form").submit();
        }`

UPDATE:
Here is a JSFiddle with a simplified form example and the code from the .js file: https://jsfiddle.net/arcanepsyche/1gprhshy/2/

Comment: Firefox haven't issues with submit forms, just it have a secure layer to avoid submitting forms without a submit button or forms that aren't attached to DOM. Maybe is this your problem, but I can't see nothing with your shared code. You must to work a little and provide us a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: The link I provided is the full, complete example. It's the entire code of the the forms and the jquery. Also, as I stated in my question, I'm aware of the Firefox security issues around forms and jquery and my forms do not fall under either category as far as I can tell. They are generated with PHP and the have a submit button.

Comment: Ok, but that's the problem. You share a full code, nobody here goes to read all your code. Look at the rules of stackoverflow.com and read the help about "how to ask" and "mcve" (minimal, complete and verifiable example)

Comment: What does this function `get_field('submit_value');` do. ?

Comment: `get_field('submit_value')` gets a text string that changes the text of the button. It's on option that the user can set on each form they create. Anything using get_field or get_sub_field or anything similar is grabbing custom field data from the Wordpress backend.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I see what you mean. I will attempt to edit the question later with a re-built example. It's just quite a complicated application to simplify down...

Comment: Maybe if you can copy and paste the generated form and put it in a jsfiddle.net you can save time providing the example. Sorry for that, but I can't spend time in read that big code. However I will stay attention to this topic to come back when it's ready

Comment: I've finally made it back to this question. I've editing my original post with a JSFiddle link that has the html of the a form plus the javascript being used.

Comment: Does your code pass html validation? If not, fix it and you may find it works.